# Set location of yarn bin directory for executables of global packages

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I can get path of yarn global bin directory with:

```
yarn global bin
```

(this prints `/home/diraria/.yarn/bin`)

How can I change this location (for example to `/usr/local/bin`)?